# does 戋 have any meaning of its own?

Tags: kanji

I see 戋 as part of several kanjis like in this table segments

[image]

. I looked for its meaning in tables and dictionaries and I couldnt find anything. Does 戋 have a meaning of its own?

Comment: Are you really wanting to ask about 戋? To me it makes more sense to ask about 戈 (one stroke less) or 㦮 (one stroke more)

Comment: 戋 is Simplified Chinese. Traditional Chinese writes it like 戔 and Japanese Shinjitai writes it like 㦮. I can't imagine where you would see 戋 in Japanese text; can you edit the question to include where you saw it in Japanese? Otherwise the question isn't really relevant here..

Comment: @drooze I saw them here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_j%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji , see how shallow and tread kanjis are written there, but what it is weird (to me) is that whan when I copy them here (after you suggested so) they are copied with one stroke more even when there they have one stroke less

Comment: I don't see 戋 in 'shallow' or 'tread' in that page, I only see 㦮. If you're asking about 㦮 (not 戋, although they have the same origins), then you should edit the question and details. Your web browser might be using a really strange font.

Comment: @drooze in that page, to me, it displays 戋 in 'shallow' and  'tread' . I would post a screencapture in the comment but it doesnt allow it.

Comment: I added a screencapture to the main topic.

Comment: Oh...this is a Han unification problem. Simplified Chinese and Japanese uses the same codepoint for characters containing 戋/㦮, and if your browser doesn't detect the right language, it'll choose the incorrect font to display it. Your browser's having a few issues here, and to most other people they'll see 㦮 on the same page you linked. Anyway...are you still asking the question for 㦮?

Comment: You could answer everything you said here and I'll mark it as accepted. Other people might find the same issue, then if I understood correctly 戋 doesnt exist in japanese and 㦮 is part of several japanese words and I still dont know what it means https://jisho.org/search/%E3%A6%AE returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, the question is asking about the shared component「㦮」in characters like「践」,「銭」, and「浅」, and unfortunately, pending on your browser settings, these may be displayed as their Simplified Chinese version with the component「戋」(one less stroke) due to [Han unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification).

Simplified Chinese「戋」and Shinjitai「㦮」actually have the same origin, so for this question the specific one that's being asked is not important; they are stroke simplifications of what was originally written「戔」, preserved in the Jōyō kyūjitai kanji「箋」. Note that its Shinjitai form「䇳」is actually Hyōgai.

---

「戔」originally depicted a compound of two pole-arm weapons「戈」.

[image]

It was originally used in two senses in ancient Chinese texts, translated in Japanese Dictionaries by the *kun'yomi* entries that are sometimes given for this character (損なう,  余り, 狭い).

- As the original character for「殘」(Shinjitai:「残」), which in a generic sense means to *harm*, extended to mean *the remainder (of an object, e.g. after damaging it)*
- Preserved in some old Chinese words such as「戔戔」, which means *having the appearance of being small/thin/narrow*.

The above two meanings may be related in some sense. In any case, there are quite a few characters that use「[戔]{せん}」as a phonetic component.

- 「箋」, *a piece of paper/a note/bamboo slip*
- 「錢」(銭), *money*, originally *a farming tool*
- 「踐」, *to trample*
- 「綫」, variant of「線」

Some of them even inherit the *small/damaged* meaning as well.

- 「淺」(浅), *shallow*
- 「賤」, *cheap/worthless*